# Fresh install of TL2018: no tikz graph drawing libraries found

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, texlive, tikz-graphdrawing

On a fresh install of TL 2018, on Linux, no tikz graph drawing libraries can be found.

The files, e.g. `texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/graphdrawing/tex/pgflibrarygraphdrawing.trees.code.tex` are there.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}



\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

Compiling with lualatex yields 

`! Package pgf Error: Graph drawing library 'trees' not found.`

Comment: See https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues/6

Comment: Do read this right, that pgf uses an internal function from luaotfload and that internal function got its API changed?

Comment: Hell, dependency management in TeX is even worse than javascript, in javascript there it at least exists.

Comment: @MaxNoe This is Lua code, not TeX, and the API concerned isn't one for font loading ...

Comment: @MaxNoe Also, as the change is a propagation from ConTeXt, and as the function concerned is almost certainly there specifically for ConTeXt support, I don't think one can really blame `luaotfload`.

Comment: Does not change the fact, that this lua code is a dependency of TeX code, right?

Comment: I don't blame luaotfload. PGF probably should have never used an internal function from luaotfload

Comment: I'm not sure that they meant to use a luaotfload function, the code is probably meant for the use as a context library. The problem is that the generic fontloader used by luaotfload has such a function too, and this has changed. I asked on the context list, if there is a better solution then asking pgf to change its code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As detailed in the https://github.com/u-fischer/luaotfload/issues/6, `pgf_lookup_and_require` wrongly uses `resolvers.findfile` to find the graph drawing libraries when used with ConTeXt.  This bug surfaced when `luaotfload` was upgraded which now also the `resolvers.findfile` function.

The problem is clearly with PGF here, because `resolvers.findfile` is to find fonts and not arbitrary files in the TeX tree.  Until this is fixed, you can override the `pgf_lookup_and_require` function with your own variant which does the correct thing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
function pgf_lookup_and_require(name)
    local sep = package.config:sub(1,1)
    local function lookup(name)
        local sub = name:gsub('%.',sep)  
        if kpse.find_file(sub, 'lua') then
            require(name)
        elseif kpse.find_file(sub, 'clua') then
            collectgarbage('stop') 
            require(name)
            collectgarbage('restart')
        else
            return false
        end
        return true
    end
    return
        lookup('pgf.gd.' .. name .. '.library') or
        lookup('pgf.gd.' .. name) or
        lookup(name .. '.library') or
        lookup(name) 
end
```

```
\end{luacode*}

\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

It seems to me that the Lua code in PGF is not so well thought through as this simple function already exhibits some Lua antipatterns, such as polluting the global environment by `require` instead of returning a table and stopping and restarting the garbage collector, which forces a collection cycle.  Also this clumsy way of determining the path separator instead of using [`package.config`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.config) should really be avoided.

Comment: For determining path separator, what's wrong with `os.type` (as it's either `windows` or 'something else')? I've looked at `package.config` and felt that this approach is much less clear.

Comment: @JosephWright The `package.config` way is the documented way and hence preferred.  I guess `os.type` would also be okay, but that is not what PGF is doing.  PGF checks whether the entries in the `PATH` environment variable are delimited by `;` (which is the case on Windows).  Furthermore `local sep = package.config:sub(1,1)` takes only a single line.

Comment: Sure: I'm thinking for `l3build` where we have quite a lot of things to do. I'd not looked at the `pgf` code: that sounds scary!

Comment: `resolvers.findfile` was already in luaotfload before, it only handled the lua type differently.

Comment: For anyone not willing to click through the issue, the bug was fixed in `pgf`.