# How can I do this Feyman diagram with tikzfeyman in latex?

Tags: luatex, tikz-feynman, feynman

[image]

So I was wondering if anyone could provide input as how i can do this diagram in latex with tikzfeymann package. Thanks!

this is pretty much what I got

```
\feynmandiagram [large, layered layout, horizontal=a to b] { % Draw the     top and bottom lines
i1 [particle=\(u\)]
-- [fermion] a -- b -- [fermion] f1 [particle=\(u\)],
i2 [particle=\(\overline s\)]
-- [fermion] c -- d -- [fermion] f2 [particle=\(\overline d\)],
% Draw the two external fermion lines
{ [same layer] a -- [charged boson, edge label'=\(W^+\)] c },
{ [same layer] b -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(\nu_e\)] d},
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is not a physics site, I refuse to draw the above diagram since in your diagram charge is not conserved and you do IMHO not treat antiparticles properly. A neutral pion is *not* composed of `u \bar d`, this is a charged pion. Here is what I propose instead:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (i1) {\(u\)}; 
\vertex[right=2cm of i1] (f1) {\(u\)};
\vertex[below=2em of i1] (i2) {\(\bar s\)};
\vertex[below=2em of f1] (f2) {\(\bar u\)};
\vertex[below=2em of f2] (f3) {\(e^+\)};
\vertex[below=2em of f3] (f4) {\(\nu_e\)};
\vertex at ($(i2)!0.5!(f2)$) (v1);
\coordinate (aux1) at ($(f3)!0.5!(f4)$);
\coordinate (aux2) at (aux1-|v1);
\vertex at ($(aux1)!0.8!(aux2)$) (v2);
\diagram* {
(i1) -- [fermion] (f1),
(i2) -- [anti fermion] (v1) -- [anti fermion] (f2),
(v1) -- [charged boson, edge label'=\(W^+\)] (v2),
(f3) -- [fermion] (v2) -- [fermion] (f4)
};
\draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (i2.south west) -- (i1.north west) node
[pos=0.5, left] {\(K^+\)};
\draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (f1.north east) -- (f2.south east) node [pos=0.5, right] {\(\pi^{0}\)};
\end{feynman} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, in case you have problems compiling this with `lualatex`, please do not blame me for that. Rather have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455001/updated-lualatex-vs-tikz-feynman) and, more importantly, [this way to fix it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453157/121799). Note that has absolutely nothing to do with my answer, rather any diagram compiled with `lualatex` will have the same problem. Personally, I was never too excited by the graph drawing algorithms, so I almost always draw my diagrams such that they can be compiled with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Please keep comments (end content) to the TeX-related aspects of the question.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, will do, as far as I can. For me reproducing the OP's diagram would be simply wrong, like typesetting an equation `1+1=3`. I have seen others correcting mathematical results, too. In fact, if I had not corrected the diagram, I am sure that there will be sooner or later a comment like : "You seem to have missed that charge is not conserved in your process." If that means that this answer needs to be deleted, so be it.

Comment: Sure, in general some 'tidy up' is welcome, but if it becomes a distraction then keeping the site scope in mind is a good idea.

Comment: @JosephWright Well, I provided a corrected diagram which has the shape of the diagram shown on the OP's screen shot. To be honest, I do not see what is too distracting about it. Yes, I am fine with the lower part of my answer being removed, yet it contained response to IMHO inappropriate comments that are luckily gone thanks to your removal. But I can't see how I should leave comments like "your code does not compile, do you do that on purpose?" completely unanswered because all versions of my answer did compile.