# Tikz-Feynman plots messed up in Texstudio

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I try to compile the following file -

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[inline=(b),vertical=a to b, green!40!black] {
a -- b -- {c [particle=\(c\)], d [particle=\(d\)]}
};
\end{document}
```

But instead of getting the image in the left, I get the on on the right - 
    [image]
How to fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to compile with `lualatex`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Then I get errors like "Package pgf Error: Graph drawing library 'trees' not found. " and "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/graphs/spring layout' "

Comment: There are some problems with the graph drawing algorithms, which have been addressed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453157/121799). However, AFAIK [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455001/121799) has not yet been fixed. So, if I am not mistaken, you may want to try not to use the graph drawing algorithms, but this diagram is simple enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must compile with LuaLaTeX in order to get the expected output. However, due to a bug in the Lua code, some fix is necessary, see https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/493/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453157/4427

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function pgf_lookup_and_require(name)
    local sep = package.config:sub(1,1)
    local function lookup(name)
        local sub = name:gsub('%.',sep)  
        if kpse.find_file(sub, 'lua') then
            require(name)
        elseif kpse.find_file(sub, 'clua') then
            collectgarbage('stop') 
            require(name)
            collectgarbage('restart')
        else
            return false
        end
        return true
    end
    return
        lookup('pgf.gd.' .. name .. '.library') or
        lookup('pgf.gd.' .. name) or
        lookup(name .. '.library') or
        lookup(name) 
end
\end{luacode*}


\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram[inline=(b),vertical=a to b, green!40!black] {
a -- b -- {c [particle=\(c\)], d [particle=\(d\)]}
};

\end{document}
```

[image]